# keyboard cursor at the beginning of line after tty login

Tags: tty, cursor

Only once, after tty login, the keyboard cursor was at the beginning of line.  So, I saw something like this:

root@desktop:~$

but the cursor was blinking right on top of 'r' at the beginning of the line.  I can't reproduce it, however, it happened together with another weird event:

the Software Updater was telling me that for changes to take effect, I needed to reboot the system, however, what was unusual, was that I never told the Software Updater to update anything.

I switched, at some point, to a raw tty terminal to run the 'aptitude' command to check my system update state.  It seems that, apparently, a no-longer-needed linux headers package was to be removed, but there was nothing else in the update except this single package removal.  So, I attributed the weirdness to that.

Maybe, it was during this tty login, with this "non-essential" update (package removal)  pending, that the weird keyboard cursor bug happened.  I can't reproduce it though.  Is this a bug?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell us how to reproduce it? Could be a bad `$TERM` value, or a problem with `$PS1` (If `$PS1` ends with `\r`, `^M`)

Comment: @waltinator I added some more details, but to answer your question, I haven't reproduced it.  It never happened again.  Thanks.